# apache URL issues

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, url, mask

I'm sure someone has asked the same question on `serverfault` but I just don't know what to look for.

I have two subdomains from different hosts in my school. eg.

```
One is:     tr33house.domain1.school.edu
the other:  tr33house.domain2.school.edu
```

Domain `one` doesn;t support python sites so I have to put the site in domain `two` and need forward all users to domain `two` but I want some kind of url masking so I users can see domain one's name at the url when they are redirected to domain two.

I have access to both machines' `.htaccess` files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If mod_proxy is turned on for the domain1 server, you can use the `P` flag along with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^path/that/uses/python/(.*)$ http://tr33house.domain2.school.edu/path/that/has/python/$1 [L,P]
```

If there are things like redirects, and/or cookies that need their locations, paths, or domains rewritten, you can use [mod_proxy's reverse directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse):

```
ProxyPassReverse /path/that/uses/python http://tr33house.domain2.school.edu/path/that/has/python
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to point the DNS entry also to this new location?

If so, you could do that and then add one line to your vhost.conf on the host where domain one is located:

`ServerAlias tr33house.domain1.school.edu`

Apache can handle different domain names in one vhost. The url the user sees then, is the url he reached the site with.

Be aware. Google doesn't like to find the exact same content under two different URL's.

Rewriting will definitely be more expensive than that.